# import error with youtube_dl after compilation with pyinstaller

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, youtube-dl

So I recently embedded youtube_dl into my python 3 project which all works very nicely.
The problem occurs when I compile that into an exe file using:
c:/python332/scripts/pyinstaller myprogram.py
It compiles fine, but upon running the exe I get an error similar to this:
Runtime Error!

Program: C:\python332\python.exe

R6034
An application has made an attempt to load the C runtime library incorrectly.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.

This specific error occurs if I go to the directory on command line, enter py -3 then try to import youtube_dl.
Interestingly, if I go to a different directory and then run py -3 and import youtube_dl it works perfectly fine (if the load time is a whee bit slow).

As extra information, for some reason pyinstaller is including both python27.dll and python37.dll, when I would have thought it would only want python37.dll?
Looking in the dist folder of the program I can see that a msvcr90.dll is present.

I am wondering is this some sort of compilation clash where pyinstaller is mixing python 2 and python  3 together?
Is there a known fix for this?

thanks.

Comment: if you are packing it into a .exe, why are you running `py -3`?

Comment: Also, what python version is python332 exactly? A 32-bit python3 installation?

Comment: Sorry my bad, yes python332 refers to a 32 bit versionf of python 3.7.4. Also the error occurs even when running the exe file itself, but the reason I mentioned that if I run py -3 then import youtube_dl, that is where the error also crops up

Comment: Could you try to rebuild the exe from a a clean venv? Their might be a few packages that somehow mess with pyinstaller, after all youtube_dl can't be the culprit since it is pure python.

Comment: @MegaIng I don't quite understand. I just run python on windows/ I might be being dum here, ssorry

Comment: Yes, but I assume that your python installation isn't very clean with lots of packages installed. You can either completely reinstall python, or try to use a [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html).

Comment: Thanks. Launching it using venv solved my issue. Also sped up somewhat too.